# Filter zabbix events by related object and host name

Tags: zabbix

I am trying to use the *event.get* method to select recent events and filter them by related object description and host name.

Example request (without the host name and related object description filters)

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "event.get",
    "params": {
        "time_from": "1518016133",
        "filter": {
          "value": 1
        },
        "selectRelatedObject": ["description"],
        "selectHost": ["name"]
    },
    "id": 2,
    "auth": "474aeddd05bb5e5f7fc0e7267fbd2sd6"
}
```

Example response

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": [
        {
            "eventid": "24397263",
            "source": "0",
            "object": "0",
            "objectid": "98218",
            "clock": "1518016248",
            "value": "1",
            "acknowledged": "0",
            "ns": "850595734",
            "hosts": [
                {
                    "hostid": "11513",
                    "name": "OS-1-LIVE"
                }
            ],
            "relatedObject": {
                "triggerid": "98218",
                "description": "No response"
            }
        }
    ],
    "id": 2
}
```

I have tried to add the following to the filter block (one at a time)

```
"hosts.name": "TEST"
"hosts[name]": "TEST"
"selectHosts.name": "TEST"
"selectHosts[name]": "TEST"
"relatedObject.description": "TEST"
```

but none of them work. (All of the results still returned)

Is it possible to filter events by related object and host name?

Zabbix API version 3.0.14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited after more research.

The parameters of event.get applies to the [event object](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/api/reference/event/object#event) only: you can filter on value, acknowleged, hostids, groupids etc, but you cannot use it to filter the output by host names.

You can use the hostids param (see [API](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/api/reference/event/get)), but you have to call the API first to convert your target host names to host IDs.

Or you can use `selectHosts = 'extend'` only, which will return a list of events and hosts with full details for a time frame, then iterate the results and filter by your criteria.

The first one requires more API calls but I think it's more elegant. The second one will return all events for all hosts of a specific time frame, then you'll have to filter out all the non-needed ones.

Python sample with hostids filtering:

```
hostId = zapi.get_id('host', item="TEST host name")
eventObj = zapi.event.get(time_from=1515771918, hostids=hostId, value="1", selectHosts='extend')

for event in eventObj:
    for host in event['hosts']:
        # filter by host['description'] or any other host value
```

Python sample without hostids filtering:

```
eventObj = zapi.event.get(time_from=1515771918, value="1", selectHosts='extend')

for event in eventObj:
    for host in event['hosts']:
            # filter by host['name'] or host['description'] or any other host value
```

In both cases, the extend output will provide full host information foreach event:

```
[
    {
        "acknowledged": "0", 
        "c_eventid": "0", 
        "clock": "1515773211", 
        "correlationid": "0", 
        "eventid": "2738610", 
        "hosts": [
            {
                "available": "0", 
                "description": "Host description", 
                "disable_until": "0", 
                "error": "", 
                "errors_from": "0", 
                "flags": "0", 
                "host": "192.168.1.1", 
                "hostid": "10283", 
                "ipmi_authtype": "-1", 
                "ipmi_available": "0", 
                "ipmi_disable_until": "0", 
                "ipmi_error": "", 
                "ipmi_errors_from": "0", 
                "ipmi_password": "", 
                "ipmi_privilege": "2", 
                "ipmi_username": "", 
                "jmx_available": "0", 
                "jmx_disable_until": "0", 
                "jmx_error": "", 
                "jmx_errors_from": "0", 
                "lastaccess": "0", 
                "maintenance_from": "0", 
                "maintenance_status": "0", 
                "maintenance_type": "0", 
                "maintenanceid": "0", 
                "name": "Your device name or hostname", 
                "proxy_hostid": "0", 
                "snmp_available": "1", 
                "snmp_disable_until": "0", 
                "snmp_error": "", 
                "snmp_errors_from": "0", 
                "status": "0", 
                "templateid": "0", 
                "tls_accept": "1", 
                "tls_connect": "1", 
                "tls_issuer": "", 
                "tls_psk": "", 
                "tls_psk_identity": "", 
                "tls_subject": ""
            }
        ], 
        "ns": "259800604", 
        "object": "0", 
        "objectid": "15177", 
        "r_eventid": "2738613", 
        "source": "0", 
        "userid": "0", 
        "value": "1"
    }, 

    -- other events -- 

]
```

You can use selectHosts to limit the values retrieved by using an array of properties in place of 'extend':

```
eventObj = zapi.event.get(time_from=1515771918, hostids=hostId, value="1", selectHosts=['description', 'status', 'host'])
```

This request will return the events with this host format:

```
 {
        "acknowledged": "0", 
        "c_eventid": "0", 
        "clock": "1516502139", 
        "correlationid": "0", 
        "eventid": "2768212", 
        "hosts": [
            {
                "description": "Test server for API experiments", 
                "host": "Test Server", 
                "hostid": "10270", 
                "status": "0"
            }
        ], 
        "ns": "536030065", 
        "object": "0", 
        "objectid": "14920", 
        "r_eventid": "0", 
        "source": "0", 
        "userid": "0", 
        "value": "1"
    },
```

Comment: A small note: selectRelatedObject refers to the **trigger** which created the event, not the host!

Comment: just to be clear, if in my example, I'd use selectHosts = 'TEST' then I would  only get events from that host?

Comment: Yes, the same python snip with `eventObj = zapi.event.get(time_from=1515771918, filter=filterObj, selectHosts='Test')` will return N events like:
 {
        "acknowledged": "0", 
        "c_eventid": "0", 
        "clock": "1515773211", 
        "correlationid": "0", 
        "eventid": "2738610", 
        "hosts": [
            {
                "hostid": "10283"
            }
        ], 
        "ns": "259800604", 
        "object": "0", 
        "objectid": "15177", 
        "r_eventid": "2738613", 
        "source": "0", 
        "userid": "0", 
        "value": "1"
},

Comment: Mhh wait, I'm having a weird behavior on selectHost without extend mode, need to check it

Comment: Ok, found it:
Can be defined as an array of property names to return only specific properties, or as one of the predefined values: 
extend - returns all object properties; 
count - returns the number of retrieved records, supported only by certain subselects.

I'll edit the answer with more details

Comment: yes, but can the Zabbix API filter the results by those properties?

Comment: I've just edited the original answer with more examples

Answer (score 0):

```
"""
Shows a list of all current issues (AKA tripped triggers)
"""
from datetime import datetime
import time
from pyzabbix import ZabbixAPI

# The hostname at which the Zabbix web interface is available
ZABBIX_SERVER = 'http://192.168.***.***/zabbix'

zapi = ZabbixAPI(ZABBIX_SERVER)

# Login to the Zabbix API
zapi.login('***', '***')

# Get a list of all issues (AKA tripped triggers)   
 triggers = zapi.trigger.get(only_true=1,
                                skipDependent=1,
                                monitored=1,
                                active=1,
                                filter={"value": 1},
                                output='extend',
                                expandDescription=1,
                                selectHosts=['name'],
                                sortfield=['lastchange'],
                                sortorder='ASC',
                                )
    
    # Do another query to find out which issues are Unacknowledged
    unack_triggers = zapi.trigger.get(only_true=1,
                                      skipDependent=1,
                                      monitored=1,
                                      active=1,
                                      output='extend',
                                      expandDescription=1,
                                      selectHosts=['host'],
                                      withLastEventUnacknowledged=1,
                                      )
    def seconds_to_dhms(time):
        seconds_to_minute   = 60
        seconds_to_hour     = 60 * seconds_to_minute
        seconds_to_day      = 24 * seconds_to_hour
        seconds_to_month    = 30 * seconds_to_day    
        seconds_to_year     = 12 * seconds_to_month
        
    
        years   =   time // seconds_to_year
        time    %=  seconds_to_year
        
        month   =   time // seconds_to_month
        time    %=  seconds_to_month
        
        days    =   time // seconds_to_day
        time    %=  seconds_to_day
    
        hours   =   time // seconds_to_hour
        time    %=  seconds_to_hour
    
        minutes =   time // seconds_to_minute
        time    %=  seconds_to_minute
    
        seconds = time
        
        if (seconds >= 0) and (minutes == 0) and (hours == 0) and (days == 0) and (month == 0) and (years == 0):
            return("%d seconds" % (seconds))   
        elif (seconds >= 0) and (minutes >= 1) and (hours == 0) and (days == 0) and (month == 0) and (years == 0):
            return("%d minutes : %d seconds" % (minutes, seconds))    
        elif (seconds >= 0) and (minutes >= 0) and (hours >= 1) and (days == 0) and (month == 0) and (years == 0):
            return("%d hours : %d minutes" % (hours, minutes))   
        elif (seconds >= 0) and (minutes >= 0) and (hours >= 0) and (days >= 1) and (month == 0) and (years == 0):
            return("%d days : %d hours" % (days, hours))
        elif (seconds >= 0) and (minutes >= 0) and (hours >= 0) and (days >= 0) and (month >= 1) and (years == 0):
            return("%d month : %d days" % (month, days))   
        elif (seconds >= 0) and (minutes >= 0) and (hours >= 0) and (days >= 0) and (month >= 0) and (years >= 1):
            return("%d year : %d month" % (years, month))       
        else:    
            return("%dm:%dd:%dh:%dm:%ds" % (month, days, hours, minutes, seconds)) 
            
    # Print a list containing only "tripped" triggers
    for t in triggers:
        if int(t['value']) == 1:
            time_period=int(time.mktime(datetime.now().timetuple())) - int(t['lastchange'])
            
            hostss=zapi.host.get(hostids=t['hosts'][0]['hostid'], output = ['hostid','host','name'], selectInterfaces=['ip','port','dns'])   
            for i in hostss:
                print("-----")
                print("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}".format(t['hosts'][0]['name'],i['interfaces'][0]['ip'], t['description'], seconds_to_dhms(time_period)))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).